# Ollydbg - debug program as administrator

Tags: ollydbg

I have a WIN32 program which I need to debug. It has to be ran as administrator - otherwise it doesn't do its job. I've searched through options and settings, but I haven't found anything usefull.

Does someone know a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Ollydbg itself needs to be run as administrator
```

In fact every debugger needs admin privileges to work correctly
a debugee is a child process of the debugger and it automatically gets admin privileges.

if your question means how to run ollydbg as administrator from a limited account

you can use the runas utility

start run cmd.exe

runas /user:machine\

when the prompt for password appears provide admin password

```
runas:\>runas /user:host\admin OLLYDBG.EXE
Enter the password for host\admin:
Attempting to start OLLYDBG.EXE as user "host\admin" ...
```

ollydbg started as admin and any debugge opened by ollydbg will have admin privileges

to check the access rights of both debugee and debugger use accesscheck from sysinternals

it will let you know who is running what

use `accesschk by sysinternals` to check the rights of debugee

```
accesschk.exe -p ollydbg 
Accesschk v4.20 - 
Reports effective permissions for securable objects 
Copyright (C) 2006-2008 Mark Russinovich 
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com 
[4056] OLLYDBG.EXE RW XXXXXX\Admin 
RW NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 
[3868] OLLYDBG.EXE RW XXXXX\guest 
RW NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
```

Comment: I want to start the debugged application as admin. If I run debugger the app it controlls doesn't have admin privileges.

Comment: Okay, there is a admin chceck in the program then :) Im going to patch it in that case. Thanks and dont forget to put in answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run ollydbg as admin {or any other application}

1. Right-Click -> Run as Admin
2. Right-Click -> Properties -> Compatibility -> Check 'Run as Admin' Option